# How is this code hiding the symbol from the linker?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In SceneView.h:

```
#ifndef ProtoAlpha_SceneView_h
#define ProtoAlpha_SceneView_h

#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "SceneModel.h"
#include "SceneController.h"
#include "CharacterModel.h"
#include "CharacterDerived.h"

USING_NS_CC;

class SceneView : public CCLayer {
private:
    static SceneModel* sceneModel;
    static SceneView* sceneViewLayer;
    static SceneController* sceneControllerLayer;
    CharacterModel* t1;
    CharacterModel* t2;
    CCSprite* t1Sprite;

    // scheduled Update 
    void update(float dt);
```

In SceneView.ccp:

```
CCScene* SceneView::scene() {
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
    CCScene* scene = CCScene::create();

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object
    sceneModel = new SceneModel;
    sceneViewLayer = SceneView::create();
    sceneControllerLayer = new SceneController(*sceneModel->buffer);

    // add layer as a child to scene
    scene->addChild(sceneViewLayer);
    scene->addChild(sceneControllerLayer);

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
```

And the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "SceneView::sceneModel", referenced from:
      SceneView::scene() in SceneView.o
      SceneView::update(float) in SceneView.o
  "SceneView::sceneViewLayer", referenced from:
      SceneView::scene() in SceneView.o
  "SceneView::sceneControllerLayer", referenced from:
      SceneView::scene() in SceneView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I were to comment out the code in the .ccp file, the linker error would go away so it is unlikely to be a compile source error.

From a bit of searching I found a few people referencing that the symbol for this code may some how be hidden, I wish to understand what's actually going on in here.

Comment: You have to initialize static members in the compilation unit. e.g: `SceneModel* SceneView::sceneModel = 0`

Comment: You have only declared the missing symbols, you have not defined them. That is what the linker is telling you. Just the same as if you'd only written a function protoype but forgotten to write the function definition.

Comment: @Paranaix

I've tried defining them in the header file itself, however that was not allowed, then I tried defining them in the constructor, and the same error occurs.

Comment: @Hobbyist It simply have to be in your compilation unit (not in a function/defition and not in the class defition. Just put it at the begining of your .cpp file (after the includes ofc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static SceneModel* sceneModel;
static SceneView* sceneViewLayer;
static SceneController* sceneControllerLayer;
```

These are all declarations that are not definitions because they are `static`. You also need to provide definitions for these members:

```
SceneModel* SceneView::sceneModel;
SceneView* SceneView::sceneViewLayer;
SceneController* SceneView::sceneControllerLayer;
```

Make sure these are only in a single translation unit (probably in `SceneView.cpp`), otherwise you'll be breaking the one definition rule.

Comment: @Paranaix Header guards only stop a header being included multiple times in the same translation unit. It would still result in multiple definitions across the entire program.

Comment: Doing so ends up in another error; ' Extra qualification on member 'sceneModel' '

Comment: @Hobbyist Note that this should be *outside* the class definition. As I said, it's probably best in `SceneView.cpp`.

Comment: @sftrabbit I realized that very soon after writing the comment, therefore I deleted it.

Comment: @sftrabbit
Your advice and Paranaix's advice did help, however I had to do it without the class's prefix and had to delete them from within the class's private scope, why is this so?

Comment: @Hobbyist Well now you've got normal global variables instead of static member variables. What was the problem with doing it as I described?

Comment: @sftrabbit & Paranaix

I managed to figure out what was wrong by reading this: 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/s1sb61xd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Thanks for all your time guys!